# How to perform calculation if there a numerous text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform a calculation on the difference between the number the user has entered in a text input for each answer in a question, and the total marks for the question.

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTXy5/1/) application which currently do this. When you change a value with in an  answer's text input, it will calculate the difference between that number entered and the total marks which belongs to that question.

My problem is that at the moment it only works if I have either one or 2 answers. But a question can have numerous answers, they can have 3, 4, 5 even 10 answers and more. So my question is that how can the fiddle below can be changed so that it can perform calculations for multiple textboxes, not just 2 text boxes?

http://jsfiddle.net/jTXy5/3/ This jsfiddle has a question which contains 3 answers. But the third text input doesn't get calculated

Below is the example of what should happen:

```
 Question No.   Question                 Answer     Marks per Answer    Total Marks
 1              Here are 2 answers       B          (text input) = 2        1
                                         D          (text input) = 1
                                         E          (text input) = 1
 2              Here is a single answer  True       (text input) = 5        0
```

As you can see in the table above, the text inputs for the answers in question 1 equals 4 altogether. So 5 (from total marks for question 1) minus 4 = 1 (Total marks now equals 1)

For question 2, the text input for the answer in question 2 equals 5, so 5 (from total marks for question 2) minus 5 = 0 (Total marks now equals 0).

Below is the code which performs the calculation:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this).find('input');
    var $row = $(this);
    var is_multiple = !$input.prop('readonly');
    var rowClass = is_multiple ? 'multiple' : 'single';
    if (is_multiple) {
        var is_first = $row.find('td').length == 5;
        rowClass += is_first ? ' first' : ' second';
    } else {
        /* readonly just needs marks changed once on page load */
        $row.find('.noofmarkstd').text(5 - $input.val());
    }
    $input.addClass(rowClass);
});

$('input.multiple').keyup(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    var is_first = $input.is('.first');
    var $row = $input.closest('tr');
    var $otherRow = $row[is_first ? 'next' : 'prev']();
    var $marks = is_first ? $row.find('.noofmarkstd') : $otherRow.find('.noofmarkstd');

    var calcs = 5 - ($input.val() || 0) - ( $otherRow.find('input.multiple').val() || 0);
    $marks.text(calcs);    
});

/* if need calcs for multiples generated on pageload trigger a change on the first in set*/
 $('input.first').change();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do when the user enters some number .. Providing an example scenario should be of help

Comment: @Sushanth-- I have updated question to provide an example on what should happen

Comment: According to your HTML structure , looks like it is gonna get complicated calculating the values you are referring to  .. If all the answers for a Question are in a single row that makes sense .. But I see that your answers itself span into multiple rows

Comment: @Sushanth-- Yes but I can have all answers in one row because each answer will have its own individual mark. That's why there are seperated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $inputs = $('input.individualMarks');

$inputs.filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('readonly') === true;
}).each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);

    var $marks = $input.closest('tr').css('color', 'red').find('td.noofmarkstd');
    $marks.html(5 - ($input.val() || 0) + '<br>(single test)');
});

$inputs.filter('[data-q_group]').keyup(function() {
    var $group = $inputs.filter('[data-q_group="' + $(this).data('q_group') + '"]');
    var $marks = $group.eq(0).closest('tr').find('td.noofmarkstd');
    var markVal = 5;
    $group.each(function() {
        markVal -= ($(this).val() || 0)
    })
    $marks.text(markVal)

})​
```